# key dictionary of .mat file python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

How can i access and plot all variables from .mat file, without specifying keys of variables in code?

How can i "parsing" .mat file?

```
    import scipy.io
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat('D:\\PROJECT\\mat files\\test.mat')
    from pylab import *
    print mat["TEMPERATURE_V1_Max"]
    time = []
    val = []
    for i in range(0,len(mat["TEMPERATURE_V1_Max"])):
        time.append(mat["TEMPERATURE_V1_Max"][i][0])
        val.append(mat["TEMPERATURE_V1_Max"][i][1])
    plot(time, val)
    ##savefig('D:\PROJECT\mat files\test' + '.png')
    show()
```

The .mat file can be found [here](http://dfiles.eu/files/pwb2efhqn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mappings should follow the [mapping protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Assuming the object created by loading the .mat file is a proper mapping you can use any of those operations on it, including the methods that return keys, values, and items.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!

Now it works:

```
    import scipy.io
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat('D:\\PROJECT\\mat files\\test.mat')
    from pylab import *

    dictMain = []
    dict_var = {"Time": [], "Value" : []}


    for key in mat.keys():
        for temp in mat[key]:
            dict_var["Time"].append(temp[0])
            dict_var["Value"].append(temp[1])
           ## plot(dict_var["Time"], dict_var["Value"])
           ## show()
        dictMain.append(dict_var)
```